# Can't resolve differential equation ${y}'=(x+y)^{1/3}-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having some problems resolving this equation:

$${y}'=(x+y)^{1/3}-1,\quad\textrm{where } y(0)=0$$

The suggestion to resolve this equation is : $z=y+x$.

I would appreciate if someone could give me some tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $z = y + x$, then

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dx} + 1$$

and $z(0) = y(0) + 0 = 0$. So your IVP is equivalent to the IVP

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = z^{1/3}; \quad z(0) = 0,$$

which I leave to you to solve.

Comment: Thanks ! Never thought on using derivatives on both sides.

Comment: @EmanuelCamacho Slightly confused about using derivatives on both sides? I would hate for you to go away thinking that this is what you are doing..

Comment: So, what am I doing ? @Chinny84

Comment: It's a substitution. You're expressing $dy/dx$ in terms of $dz/dx$

Comment: @emanuel sorry for the slow reply. But it's aa Dylan states - a sub not taking derivative both sides (you are subbing one derivarive for another)